# Android Studio Emulator seems incomplete?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have installed the latest Version of `Android Studio`. Now I like to set up an `Emulator`. I had used the `SDK Manager` to load the `Intel Atom Image`, and set up an **AVD**.
I think I have done this like in all other Examples but if I start the `Emulator`, all what I can se is an empty home screen without any other icons or setting. I thought the `emulator` would be like an real device, or quite close to it.
Maybe I think wrong?
But I had seen videos where the `emulator` is like an real phone.
What can i do to get my `emulator` to an pretty phone? :)

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if in your emulator parameters the "hardware buttons" are checked. However, sometimes android studio emulators are giving some errors. You can try download [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulators for android, if you don't lack ram it will work out pretty well for you.

Comment: So i think i have enabled the option, but no change. Maybe take a look at what i mean: [link](http://i.imgur.com/e5UPzXK.png)

The left one is what i want, the right one is what i got :( But thank you for your answer i will try Genymotion :)

Comment: maybe try to reset your emulator (delete and create new)